# Why am I getting commas in my return value? JavaScript Celebrity Name Revealer

Tags: javascript, arrays, return-value, console.log

Here is my code, I'm getting commas in between my names in the message returned

[CodePen: Celebrity Name Revealer](http://codepen.io/httpJunkie/pen/prkon?editors=101)

```
var MarilynMonroe=["Norma", "Jean", "Mortensen"];
var WoodyAllen=["Allen", "Konigsberg"];
var MegRyan=["Margaret", "Mary", "Emily", "Anne Hyra"];

function nameMaker () {
    msg = "The name is ";
    for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        msg += arguments[i] + " ";
    }
    return(msg);
}

console.log(nameMaker(MarilynMonroe));
console.log(nameMaker(WoodyAllen));
console.log(nameMaker(MegRyan));
```

I was hoping to have a space between them, but if you change the space in the string I added to lets say an exclamation point you will see that it just appends that to the end of the entire phrase and that confuses me as well.

I have created a code pen.

[CodePen: Celebrity Name Revealer](http://codepen.io/httpJunkie/pen/prkon?editors=101)

---

***I ended up with the following solution for this question:***

```
var MarilynMonroe=["Norma", "Jean", "Mortensen"];
var WoodyAllen=["Allen", "Konigsberg"];
var MegRyan=["Margaret", "Mary", "Emily", "Anne Hyra"];

function nameRevealer (names) {
    msg = "This celebrity's real name is ";
    for (i=0; i<names.length; i++){
        msg += names[i] + " ";
    }
    return(msg);
}

console.log(nameMaker(MarilynMonroe));
console.log(nameMaker(WoodyAllen));
console.log(nameMaker(MegRyan));
```

Comment: `arguments` is an array like object of the arguments you pass to the function. In this case, you only ever pass 1 argument (the array). Add a parameter `names` in the function and then change arguments to `names`

Comment: Ok, but do you think you could expand on the reason why a little better in an answer. Your right that does work, but I have to be able to explain why it is and frankly I'm still a little unsure.

Comment: Compare how the function runs between what you have and what I suggested. Use the debugger to step through it. It should be pretty obvious to figure out the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arguments` variable is an array: you are passing an array as the first argument.  What is happening is that it is iterating the `arguments` array, and calling .[toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on each celebrity's array, which automatically adds the commas.  What you want is to iterate `arguments[0]`.

Something like:

```
for (var i=0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) {
    msg += arguments[0][i] + " ";
}
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to just take the arguments by name, no?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Agreed.  But OP's question was why he was getting the commas.  There could be quite a few improvements to the celebrity name revealer, I think.

Comment: This is what I needed to hear. THis explains to me why I was getting the commas. You rock and now I understand!

Comment: I have been thrusted into teaching a JS class and If I don't know the reason why,.. I can't create the examples or explain them in great detail when something goes wrong. I appreciate you understanding what I was asking and hitting the nail on the head!

Answer (score 5):

The `arguments` is an array of arrays (with just one item) in this case. To fix this, redefine nameMaker:

```
var nameMaker = function(names) {
  return 'The name is ' + names.join(' ');
};
```

Also, some other feedback regarding your code:

1. You should always declare variables with "var"; the way you are defining "msg" and "i" cause them to be global variables since you do not use "var".
2. When constructing a string by repeated iteration, it is typically faster to use a list as a builder and then use the 'join' function (if you are only concatenating a small, fixed number of strings, though, it's fine to simply use '+'; however, if you are doing += in a for-loop, switch to 'push' and 'join').

Comment: Damn, why did I do it the long way, that makes more sense. To use the join.

Comment: You would have had to see the code building up to this. I was teaching about passing arrays into functions and iterating through them. Listen I'm not the greatest JavaScript teacher. But I am trying. I may actually use what you suggested as an alternate way of doing the same thing in a more efficient manner. I'll test it out.

Comment: @EricB, it's generally a good idea to teach by example. So, if you do use "arguments" instead of passing the arguments by name, you should use it in a case where they cannot be passed by name (e.g. when the same function may be invoked with many different variations in the number of type of arguments). And definitely follow items #1 and #2.

Comment: Makes sense. I have a lot of notes to take away form this!

Comment: #1. yes because of function scope vs global scope. Point taken!
#2. I hadn't covered joins yet at this point. But I think I may move that ahead in the course so that I can use it here or use this example as a reason to segway into join method. Great comments!

Comment: Also one thing I have to be careful about is building on the concepts we have already learned and not losing them. At this point we are still just learning the basics. SO I have to walk that fine line of doing it right for the level we are at but also not getting lost by throwing concepts that may not be easy to swallow at this point in the examples.

Comment: So we actually cover joins right after this example so I will use this as an example of refactoring the initial code to something that more efficient. Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JayKandari/xdNLj  I just replicated yours in fiddle with a little change. Is that you wanted? a space between those names ?

```
    var MarilynMonroe=["Norma", "Jean", "Mortensen"];
    var WoodyAllen=["Allen", "Konigsberg"];
    var MegRyan=["Margaret", "Mary", "Emily", "Anne Hyra"];

    function nameMaker (names) {
        msg = "The name is ";
        for (i=0; i<names.length; i++){
            msg += names[i] + " ";
        }
        document.getElementById("message").innerText = (msg);
            return(msg);
    }

nameMaker(MarilynMonroe);
nameMaker(WoodyAllen);
nameMaker(MegRyan);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct solution to the overall problem, but the answer I was looking for was more of an explanation as to why I was getting the output with the commas. I did 1up your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript already takes `arguments` as array, so you don't need to pass an array.

call your function like this.

```
console.log(nameMaker("Norma", "Jean", "Mortensen"));
```

OR

change your function add a paramenter `names` and perform operation on `names` instead of `arguments`.

Comment: Ok, so this works, but I want to be able to pass in the celebrity name or name of the array that contains the real name to get the answer. The first comment I received was right on but Im unsure why I got the commas and the space didn't get applied.

Comment: The commas are from an implicit conversion from array to string. There is only one item in "arguments", namely the array that you passed-in. So your loop executes only once. It then does "+=" with a string on the left and an array on the right. The array on the right is converted to a string, and the string representation of an array is the elements converted to strings and comma-separated.

Comment: Nice explanation! ALready have a correct answer with a similar explanation, but I thank you for the detailed explanation! This helps me!

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument variable `function nameMaker (name)`
then change all `argument` to `name`

```
var MarilynMonroe=["Norma", "Jean", "Mortensen"];
var WoodyAllen=["Allen", "Konigsberg"];
var MegRyan=["Margaret", "Mary", "Emily", "Anne Hyra"];

function nameMaker (name) {
    msg = "The name is ";
    for (i=0; i<name.length; i++){
        msg += name[i] + " ";
    }
    return(msg);
}
console.log(nameMaker(MarilynMonroe));
console.log(nameMaker(WoodyAllen));
console.log(nameMaker(MegRyan));
```